# How to create one step checkout page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am creating checkout pages and after one step they are redirecting to another pages .

I want to handle all these steps on 1 pages like this

[image: Desired output]

After completing and press continue, next step  should trigger on same page.

I just need  way to do that on same page. Any sort of help would be highly appreciated

Comment: which theme you are using ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal  ultimo.

Comment: but I don't see this kind of checkout page in ultimo , using magento 2... this is like in magento 1

Comment: @ManojDeswal  I have to make like this. at this time I dont have like this its just image of how I should change my checkout

Comment: @ManojDeswal client want like this. I just want to know how a all forms will be on 1 page ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal can you post this as answer ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal   can you check this one please ?   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201773/separate-cms-pages-with-different-left-side-bar-magento-2