# Magento 2 : Separate cms pages with different left side bar

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block

I want to create pages for shipping return , faqs and two others like this . But how can I add left bar to them like this ?

[image]

Comment: These are static informative pages so you can go via using Bootstrap Column Grid or you can create you own grid using HTML CSS . Create two blocks one for main content one for sidebar and call both blocks in your page .. using left right column setup

Comment: @ManojDeswal  I have made block for main content but stuck in left menu bar ,  how to add these pages in left bar and keep active those who are active,